# Create multiple columns and rows with if-elif-else statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` with for which I am creating rows that produce the corners of rectangles. Depending on whether one of the tags is one of `S1` and `S2`, different functions need to be applied. Now, the dataframe looks like this:

```
Thing  x  y Side  length_x  length_y
0     A  1  3   S1         1         2
1     A  1  1   S2         1         2
2     B  2  3   S1         2         1
```

For this I produce a list `things = list(set(df1.Thing.unique()))` which is `things  =['S1','S2']`.

If `Side` is `S1` then, the following function needs to be applied:

```
a = df.join(df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'corner_x': [r['x']+r['length_x']/2, r['x']-r['length_x']/2],
                                                  'corner_y': [r['y'], r['y']-r['length_y']/2],}),
                             axis=1).explode('corner_x').explode('corner_y'), how='right')
```

and if `Side` is `S2`, then this function needs to be applied:

```py
b = df.join(df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'corner_x': [r['x']+r['length_x']/2, r['x']-r['length_x']/2], 
                                                  'corner_y': [r['y']+r['length_y']/2, r['y']+r['length_y']/2],}), 
                                    axis=1).explode('corner_x').explode('corner_y'),how='right')
```

Both of them work intependently, but what I want to do is do this on-the-fly. I tried:

```py
dd = []
ee = []
ff = []
for thing in things:
    df = df1[df1['Thing']=='{}'.format(thing)]
    if df['Side']=='S1': 
        a = df.join(df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'corner_x': [r['x']+r['length_x']/2, r['x']-r['length_x']/2],
                                                  'corner_y': [r['y'], r['y']-r['length_y']/2],}),
                             axis=1).explode('corner_x').explode('corner_y'), how='right')
        ee.append(a)

    elif df['Side']=='S2':
        b = df.join(df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'corner_x': [r['x']+r['length_x']/2, r['x']-r['length_x']/2], 
                                                  'corner_y': [r['y']+r['length_y']/2, r['y']+r['length_y']/2],}), 
                                    axis=1).explode('corner_x').explode('corner_y'),how='right')
        dd.append(b)

    else: 
        0
        
    EE = pd.concat(ee, ignore_index=True)
    DD = pd.concat(dd, ignore_index=True)

Full = pd.concat([EE,DD])
```

But it does work at all. I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Basically, what I am trying to do it to go through all cases and there are only two possible ones. I don't understand where the ambiguity resides. It's either `S1` or `S2`.

How can I solve this? I tried `df.assign` and `np.where` but in both cases, I fail since I am creating several columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put the condition on "Side" in the apply? Thus you won't need a loop or where…

```
df.join(df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'corner_x': [r['x']+r['length_x']/2, r['x']-r['length_x']/2],
                                      
                                      'corner_y': [r['y'], r['y']-r['length_y']/2]
                                                  if r['Side'] == 'S1' else
                                                  [r['y']+r['length_y']/2, r['y']+r['length_y']/2],
                                     }),
                 
                             axis=1).explode('corner_x').explode('corner_y'), how='right')
```

output:

```
  Thing  x  y Side  length_x  length_y corner_x corner_y
0     A  1  3   S1         1         2      1.5        3
0     A  1  3   S1         1         2      1.5        2
0     A  1  3   S1         1         2      0.5        3
0     A  1  3   S1         1         2      0.5        2
1     A  1  1   S2         1         2      1.5        2
1     A  1  1   S2         1         2      1.5        2
1     A  1  1   S2         1         2      0.5        2
1     A  1  1   S2         1         2      0.5        2
2     B  2  3   S1         2         1        3        3
2     B  2  3   S1         2         1        3      2.5
2     B  2  3   S1         2         1        1        3
2     B  2  3   S1         2         1        1      2.5
```

Comment: Thank you, again! Do you understand why the method I chose doesn't work?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't read the code in detail as using loops is inherently inefficient, especially since there is already one due to the apply. That said, `if df['Side']=='S1'` cannot work as `df['Side']=='S1'` returns a Series of booleans, and `if` expects a single value. You could have computed both possibilities (a/b) and used `df[your_cols] = a.where(condition, b)`